# Multiple source files with C++

Tags: c++, file, header

I have a simple project broken up into the following source files:

my.h:

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H

extern int val;     
void print_val();   

#endif
```

my.cpp:

```
#include "my.h"
#include <iostream>

void print_val()
{
    std::cout << val;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "my.h"

int main()
{
    val = 4;      
    print_val();  

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile I receive the following errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int val" (?val@@3HA)             
1>my.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int val" (?val@@3HA)     
1>c:\...\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Why is this so? I simply want to declare a variable and function in a header and define the function in a separate source file. I use Visual C++ 2010 Express, and the project is a Win32 Console app.

Comment: You have successfully declared the variable, but you have to define it in a cpp, just like the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `my.cpp` you probably wanted to define that extern variable of yours, like this:

```
int val; // optionally you can also initialize it here, like this: int val=0;
```

This will make sure the compiler actually allocates an object for this variable that can be later linked into your executable.

On a related note - make sure there's only **one** definition of such `extern` variable in **all** of your source files otherwise you'll have duplicate symbols and linker won't be happy with that

Comment: If that answered your question feel free to mark it as such so that whoever is searching the web and stumbles across that post will know if this is the information that was needed

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the function, but you are never declaring the variable `val`. That's why its symbol cannot be found.